# как самым простым способом сравнить изображения на полное сходство

Tags: c#, изображения, сравнение

Есть список пользователей vk и их ава, как без перебегания к машинному зрению найти пустышки (они все одинаковые)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно - попиксельно ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: можно попробовать картинку представить как набор байтов и по байтно попробовать сравнить.

Comment: Можно пример попиксельного сравнения

Comment: а эти пустышки, они не по одному ли и тому же урлу лежат?

Comment: Diff файлов вам поможет. Если файл одинаковый можно обойтись crc32 например.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться OpenCV для данной цели. Два изображения можно сравнить [так](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/3046.html) и [так](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/506.html) . Почитайте, возможно вам подойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файлы одинаковые, возможно вам поможет crc32 например:

```
CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
String hash = String.Empty;

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(fs)) 
    { 
        hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("CRC-32 is {0}", hash);
 }
```

Оригинал [тут](https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/blob/master/CSharp/DamienG.Library/Security/Cryptography/Crc32.cs) или можно вот [тут](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Checksum/Crc32.cs)

Или другая [реализация](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/35134/How-to-calculate-CRC-in-Csharp.aspx), [crc16](http://www.sanity-free.com/134/standard_crc_16_in_csharp.html)